# Use of "always" in all tenses

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect

My problem is: can "always" be used in all tenses? Which are BrE and American English?

Ex. I have always told you not to do this.

> I had always told you not to do this.
>
> I always told you not to do this

Are they possible?

Answer (score 2):

'Always' is an adverb, like 'repeatedly' for example, and as such won't change with the tense.